# remove automatic '<,'> when hitting colon in visual mode

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, visual-mode

This problem started because I want to run a command in visual mode with

```
:silent! '<,'> command here
```

however if I do a mapping

```
vnoremap ,a :silent! '<,'> command here
```

then in vim runs like

```
:'<,'>silent! '<,'> command here
```

the same happens if i use

```
vnoremap ,a :exe "silent! '<,'> command"
```

that it is converted to

```
:'<,'>exe "silent!...."
```

Comment: On a side note, prefer to exclude the select-mode -> `:xnoremap <silent> ,a :<c-u>silent! exe....`

Comment: interesting point. I will have a look. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting aside mappings for a moment, what do we do when we're manually entering commands and find a range on the command line that we don't want? Hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> five times? Well...yes...that's one possibility but there's [something better than that](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-U):

```
                                                    c_CTRL-U
CTRL-U      Remove all characters between the cursor position and
            the beginning of the line. ...
```

Since a mapping is essentially the same as the equivalent manual command we just need to translate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to something that works in Vimscript. That would be the equivalent [keycode](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#keycodes) `<C-U>`.

So add `<C-U>` at the beginning of your mapping right after the opening `:`. For example:

```
vnoremap ,a :<C-U>silent! ..etc..
```

That will clear *any* text that happens to currently be on the command line before your command(s) are applied.

Comment: I didn't remember the existence of <C-U>. Brilliant